# DataTable(s) are not getting resized when using fnAdjustColumnSizing

Tags: javascript, datatables

My application has left pane and right pane. Right pane has multiple tabs and each tab holds a datatable.

I provide the ability to expand the right pane if the users want to view just the right pane, hence I need to expand my datatables whenever the right pane is expanded.

I am currently using the below code to expand /collapse the datatables but this doesnt seem to work properly. Only one datatable (the current table that displayed on the screen) gets re sized properly, other tables are not getting re sized properly.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

```
function onCollapse(e) {
  var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
    if ( table.length > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
                $(table[i]).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}

function onExpand(e) {
    var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
    if ( table.length > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
                $(table[i]).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Barani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out a way to fix this issue.

I added the below code on activate event of the (kendo tabstrip) tab and this solved the issue.

```
    function onActivate(e) {
        var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables();
        if ( table.length > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
                    $(table[i]).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Barani

Comment: Possibly from this link on the DataTables Forum http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html